# The empty-set as a subset, and as a member

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Reading the Hammack 'Book of Proof'.

He shows that the empty-set is a subset of all possible sets.

I believe this doesn't also mean that the empty-set is also a member of all possible sets.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This is correct. For example, $\varnothing \subset\{1\}$ but $\varnothing\notin\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Consider the following sets: $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{\emptyset, 1,2\}$. Note that $\emptyset \in B$ and $\emptyset \in B-A = \{\emptyset\}$ but $\emptyset \not\in A$, even though $\emptyset$ is a subset of all the above sets.

Answer (score 1):

You are right - that *does not* mean that the emptyset is a member of every set. For example, the emptyset is not a member of the emptyset. (Why? Because the emptyset has no members at all!)